# How to stop default animation?

Tags: c#, android, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 2D (4.3) and whenever I start the game, the default animation plays. How can I stop this? I haven't told it to start in `void Start()` or anything...

Also, `animation.Play("Anim")` doesn't work.

I'll show you some screenshots of my editor:
The Animator 
[image: Animator in editor]

The animator object on my player

[image: Animator object]

Comment: Please don't preface your titles with tags. Just tag your questions appropriately and you'll be good to go.

Comment: How are people going to know what I'm using? @Bart

Comment: You already state so in your question and the tags give away that you're using Unity. There is no separate Unity 2D to begin with.

Comment: @Bart Ok, so how do I fix it?

Comment: try creating a new state default/idle with single sprite you want to be displayed at the beginning and set this state as default. then transition to the fly state appropriately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to create a new (empty) State within the Animator panel, Right-Click and select to make that the default state (should highlight orange).